# Why doesn't my service (using Apache Daemon ) work in the Services tool?

Tags: java, apache-commons-daemon

I am following [this Ulrichpalha.com tutorial for Apache Daemon](http://ulrichpalha.com/myblog/2011/11/19/using-commons-daemon-procrun-to-run-your-java-application-as-a-windows-service/) , however I'm not able to start the service from MS services.msc window :

[image]

This is at the step **Running the Sample Application**, step 4. a

I'm wondering if it is because my Apache Daemon isn't working right ([it should look like this](http://ulrichpalha.com/myblog/files/2011/11/LoggerService-exe-output.png) ).  Because when I run LoggerService.exe in the command-window I am not getting the results shown on the Ulrich site (it doesn't output anything ).

Comment: You should check Windows Event Logs, they may have some info in "Applications" log

Comment: @user996142 - thanks , I'll look at that

Comment: Maybe this question and answer of mine might be helpful to you [Howto setup a Daemon implementation as windows service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31556478/howto-setup-a-daemon-implementation-as-windows-service). It contains the call to procrun and the Java class I used to setup a Windows service with apache-daemons. During my trials I noticed that most of the examples and tutorials are not up to date anymore. You might as well check the log output of your service. By default the log files are located at `%SystemRoot%\System32\LogFiles\Apache`.